Asymptotics of 2Ai(x)Ai'(x)
I'm looking for the asymptotics of the derivative of Airy squared  $2Ai(x)Ai'(x)$ as $x\to \infty$. I know that $A i^2(x) \sim \frac{1}{4} \pi^{-1}(x)^{-1 / 2} e^{-\frac{4}{3}(x)^{3 / 2}}$. Would it be correct simply take the derivative of both sides to obtain?
$$\frac{d}{dx}Ai^2(x) = 2Ai(x)Ai'(x)\sim -\frac{e^{-\left(4 x^{3 / 2}\right) / 3}\left(4 x^{3 / 2}+1\right)}{8 \pi x^{3 / 2}}$$
Taking this one step further, using that the Airy equation satisfies $f''(x)=xf(x)$, and taking the derivative of $2Ai(x)Ai'(x)$, would it be correct to say that
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}Ai(x)=2(Ai'(x))^2+2Ai(x)Ai''(x)=2(Ai'(x))^2+2xAi^2(x) \sim\frac{e^{-\left(4 x^{3 / 2}\right) / 3}\left(4 x^{3 / 2}+16 x^3+3\right)}{16 \pi x^{5 / 2}}? $$
Thank you!

One does have to be careful: it's not necessarily true that if $f(x) \sim g(x)$ then $f'(x) \sim g'(x)$ (e.g. consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x + \sin(x)$).
Also your second term for $\text{Ai}'$ is wrong: you seem to be neglecting the later terms in the expansion for $\text{Ai}(x)$.  The correct asymptotics, according to Maple, are
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \text{Ai}^2(x) \sim -\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{4 x^{3/2}}{3}}}{2 \pi}-\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{4 x^{3/2}}{3}} }{48 \pi x^{3/2}}$$
and
$$ \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \text{Ai}^2(x) \sim \dfrac{{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{4 x^{3/2}}{3}} x^{1/2}}{\pi} + \dfrac{{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{4 x^{3/2}}{3}}}{24 \pi x} + 
\dfrac{{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{4 x^{3/2}}{3}}}{1152 \pi x^{5/2}}$$

Thanks! Would you mind sharing the maple code? I was able to compute this myself using the method of steepest descents differentiating under the integral sign of the integral version of Ai^2

map(simplify,asympt(diff(AiryAi(x)^2,x),x));
map(simplify,asympt(diff(AiryAi(x)^2,x$2),x));
